# NoSuchMethod webview evaluatejavascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, xamarin

I'm getting the error "no method with name = 'evaluateJavascript' in Landroid/webkit/Webiew" on Android 4.3

this is what i'm doing in my WebViewClient:

```
public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
    {
        if(url.Contains ("addsResponseLoaded"))
        {
            view.EvaluateJavascript ("window.giveMeMyResponse();", controller.JSResultObj);
            //view.StopLoading ();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This happens only on older version of android and specific devices like the htc and galaxy. How can i get the return value of a javascript function android older versions than android kitkat?

Answer (score 1):

A simple look at developer [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

```
public void evaluateJavascript (String script, ValueCallback<String> resultCallback)

Added in API level 19
```

Your minSdkVersion should be at least 19 for this method to work.

If you need to evaluate JavaScript on earlier versions of Android (3+), here is a little library:

https://github.com/evgenyneu/js-evaluator-for-android

Comment: how can i support older versions?

Comment: I am afraid you will need some kind of library for that. Refer here https://github.com/evgenyneu/js-evaluator-for-android

Comment: Seriously? there's no other way?

Comment: This is the only easiest way, I know so far. Either you change your target API to 19+ or use a library. The other way is to look into evaluateJavascript() source code and try to implement it, which requires some time.

Comment: my target is API 19, i guess the minimum api needs to be 19+

Comment: @Joske369 Yeah my bad. I meant minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(injectedObject.toString())");
```